# How-to : Make text div stay at the same position after hovering

Tags: html, css

I post here cause I struggle with a little issue ( btw I'm newbie at coding ).

I want to have a superscript appears on hovering a menu item ( which is working ).
But I want that the text stay centered ( actually it slide to left on hover ) and the superscript appears just next to it.

Here is the code pen of my code, I tried many different display in css …  if someone know how to  do that I would really appreciate it  Thanks in advance

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/KTHRSS/pen/jOBNLNQ)

**HTML -->**

```
<div class="menu">
        <div id="menu-item">
            <a href="./pages/index.html">Menu Item 1<span id="sup"> (&#8239passage&#8239)</span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu-item">
            <a href="./pages/index.html">Menu Item 2<span id="sup"> (&#8239empreinte&#8239)</span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu-item">
            <a href="./pages/index.html">Menu Item 3<span id="sup"> (&#8239trace&#8239)</span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu-item">
            <a href="./pages/index.html">Gallery</a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu-item">
            <a href="./pages/index.html">About</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS -->**

```
.menu {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

#site-title {
    font-size: 47px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#site-title a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu-item a {
    font-size: 47px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
}

#sup {
    vertical-align: super;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 15px;
}


#menu-item a #sup {
    display: none;
}
#menu-item a:hover #sup {
    display: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `position: absolute` to `#sup` will remove them from document flow and adding `position: relative` to its parent will stop the element from going beyond the parent element.

Also, you can use `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and `right` to align the superscript, Adjust accordingly

```css
body {
    background-color: pink;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serifs;
}


.menu {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

#site-title {
    font-size: 47px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#site-title a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu-item a {
    font-size: 47px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#sup {
    vertical-align: super;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 15px;
}


#menu-item a #sup {
    display: none;
}
#menu-item a:hover #sup {
    display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Corinne Bretel • Artiste Peintre</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="site-title">
            <a href="./pages/index.html">Site Title</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <div id="menu-item">
                <a href="./pages/index.html">Menu Item 1<span id="sup"> (&#8239passage&#8239)</span></a>
            </div>
            <div id="menu-item">
                <a href="./pages/index.html">Menu Item 2<span id="sup"> (&#8239empreinte&#8239)</span></a>
            </div>
            <div id="menu-item">
                <a href="./pages/index.html">Menu Item 3<span id="sup"> (&#8239trace&#8239)</span></a>
            </div>
            <div id="menu-item">
                <a href="./pages/index.html">Gallery</a>
            </div>
            <div id="menu-item">
                <a href="./pages/index.html">About</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks, easy apparently … I feel ashamed aha